# Missing HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/COMPONENTS

Tags: windows, windows-registry, components

A line from CBS.log

> CBS    Failed to load the COMPONENTS hive from
>   'C:\windows\System32\config\COMPONENTS' into registry key
>   'HKLM\COMPONENTS'. [HRESULT = 0x800703f1 - ERROR_BADDB]

Comment: You should reinstall Windows.